# How to connect to Windows with xfreerdp and smartcard

Tags: linux, remote-desktop

I am able to connect to Windows 2008 R2 server from Linux Mint using:

```
$ xfreerdp -f -u <username on windows> -d <windows Domain> 192.168.1.1
```

but I want to connect to that server using Smartcard.
Another try with:

```
$ xfreerdp -f --plugin rdpdr --data:smartcard -- 192.168.1.1
```

didn't make success.
What is right syntax for USB Smartcard reader 'Gemalto GemPC Twin 00 00'

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 08e6:3437 Gemplus GemPC Twin SmartCard Reader
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to compile xfreerdp source code with

> cmake -DWITH_PCSC=ON -DWITH_SSE2=ON .

To check is everything OK with smart cards and USB reader

> rdesktop -f -d *YourDomain* -u *username* -r scard:"Gemalto PC Twin Reader 00 00" *x.x.x.x*

To start xfreerdp in full screen mode

> xfreerdp /f /d:*yourDomain* /smartcard:"Gemalto PC Twin Reader 00 00" /v:*x.x.x.x*

This works for Windows 2003.

For Windows 2008 R2 you have to start xfreerdp with -sec-nla switch

> xfreerdp -sec-nla /f /d:*YourDomain* /smartcard:"Gemalto PC Twin Reader 00 00" /v:*IP address*

Comment: you must be a colleague :) 
The gemalto smartcard requires also using a custom module 
so your best bet is to have the default PKCS11 module linked to the custom gemalto one
this way you don't need to figure out how to change PKCS11 default module 
Pity that most distributions require you to recompile xfreerdp

Comment: Did you have any success ? I recompiled but I still cant use the card on the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some current info and the source of the card reader string:
(year 2020; openSuse Tumbleweed, but i expect current Linux Mint to use a simlar version of xfreerdp)

it works to connect to an Windows Server 2016 using the command:

```
xfreerdp -v:<servername> /smartcard:<string as given by pcsc_scan -r> /w:<pixel hor.> /h:<pixel vert.> /u:<loginname> /d:<domain> /dynamic-resolution
```

example:

```
~> **pcsc_scan -r**
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: OMNIKEY AG CardMan 3121 00 00
~> xfreerdp -v:server.local /smartcard:"OMNIKEY AG CardMan 3121 00 00" /w:2400 /h:1400 /u:winuser /d:mydomain /dynamic-resolution
```